# Python regex поиск переноса строки

Tags: python, строки

Как в тексте найти перенос строки соответственно символ `\n` при помощи регулярного выражения для последующей замены на пустоту/пробел? текст может быть произвольный и содержать как один перенос, так и несколько.

Comment: Если у вас в тексте есть переносы строки, значит текст у вас на эти же самые строки и разбит. Зачем вам регулярка? читайте все строки и соединяйте их через пробел.

Comment: `text.replace("\n", " ")` - зачем мудрить?

Comment: да, это работает, а можете подсказать чистое регулярное выражение которое будет искать переносы? спасибо

Comment: `re.sub("\n", " ", text)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Просьба, подсказать, как можно в тексте найти перенос строки
> соответственно символ \n при помощи регулярного выражения для
> последующей замены на пустоту/пробел,

Для поиска и удаления конкретного текста в строке вы можете использовать:

```
text.replace("\n", " ")
```